# My cat is suddenly drooling a lot while sleeping

Tags: cats

My cat is suddenly drooling excessively while sleeping. There are large wet spots on his fur or blanket. There are no other symptoms. He is playing normally and eating and drinking normally. The drooling is only while sleeping. He is only 3 yo, neutered. No changes to food, environment, anything.
He went to the vet and the vet didn’t see anything in his mouth. His heart and lungs sound good. His temperature is good. His eyes and ears are clear. The only symptom is the drooling. The vet gave him an anti inflammatory but he’s still drooling.has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Some cats do drool. Sometimes it indicates sinus or dental issues, sometimes it just means they are really, really relaxed, sometimes it means they are dreaming about food...